# Difference between alikeness and likeness

Tags: prepositions, difference, nouns

Is there any difference between "alikeness" and "likeness"?

> - My likeness to my mother is so striking.
> - My alikeness to my mother is so striking.

Can I use a preposition "to" after a noun "alikeness"?

Comment: [*Alikeness* is such a rare word](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=likeness%2Calikeness&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) that my advice would be to just not ever use it.  I'm a native English speaker and I had to check the dictionary to see whether it was a real word.

Comment: In English, both *like* and *alike* are valid adjectives, so you could form a noun from either of them. In practice, people typically use the noun from *like*, i.e. *likeness*. Curiously, the adjective *[like](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like)* is now not very common (except in a few constructions, such as after *of* e.g. "of like mind", or in compounds like *like-minded*) but the noun *likeness* is. That's just how it happened.